# tree structure in view file

Tags: java, jsp

I am facing an issue while displaying a collection in my jsp,the collection contains data something like Collection(col1,col2...) col1 is having name,value,iconname etc.
Now the requirement is that for 2 particular object i have to make 3 object child just for display purpose(these three objects are also coming in collection).I am having a field level in DB withh value 1 and 2 so i want to display it something like

```
col1
col2
col3
 *col4
 *col5
 *col6
col7... and so on. .
```

any guesses

Comment: its just a colletion to iterate have nothing to do with language

Answer (score 0):

Split the problem.

First create a java method that takes the initial collection and returns the tree. That allows you to write unit tests for it until you get it right.

Afterwards, modify the JSP to render the new tree structure.

Answer (score 0):

If you already know which 2 objects are having child nodes, you can use 
jstl c:if tag and check for the condition , and based on condition render them as a child elements.

Otherwise, it would be advisable as Aaron said , to create backing javabean and use it within your jsp.